# 2 forms with outputs on same page conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a single page with at least two (possibly will be more) forms. I tried setting a separate script for the second one while also entering in the correct ID's for each field. But regardless, it always outputs to the first output textarea. I assume there is some way I have to define each separate form for the script. I am new to all this, so not sure how to do that. Would really appreciate any assistance anyone can offer.

```
<table width="100%" height="600" border=0>
<tr>
<td width=550 valign=top>

<form name="Form1" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone number:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number"><br>

<b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No?:</font></b> <br>   
<select type="drop" name="Question1" id="question1">
<option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No 2?:</font></b><br>
<select type="drop" name="Question2" id="question2">
<option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="n/a">n/a</option>
</select>  
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Notes:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Notes" id="notes" placeholder="Problem" cols="70"  rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Issue" id="issue" placeholder="Issue" cols="70"   rows="6"></textarea>    
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Action" id="action" placeholder="Action" cols="70"  rows="10"></textarea>
<br>



</td>
<td valign="top">

<table border=0 height=100% ><tr><td valign="top" height=410>

<textarea type="textarea" name="form1output" 
onclick="this.focus();this.select()" id="output" cols="70" rows="25" 
placeholder="Name:
Number:
Y or N?:
Question?:&#x0a;
Notes:&#x0a;
Issue:&#x0a;
Action:"></textarea>
<br>

</td>

</tr>
  <tr><td valign=top>

  <div class="btn-group">
<button value="Combine" onclick="convert()">Combine</button> <br><br>
</div>


  </td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">




<table width=25% height=100% border=0><tr><td valign="bottom">

<div class="btn-group">
<button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
</div>

</form>

</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>

<hr>

<table width="100%" height="600" border=0>
<tr>
<td width=550 valign=top>

<form name="Form2" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="Name2" id="name2" placeholder="Name"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone Number:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="Currentnumber" id="currentnumber" 
placeholder="Corrent phone number"><br>

<b><font color="#2C3E60">Y or N:</font></b> <br>   
<select type="drop" name="YESNO" id="yesno">
<option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Did you offer self serve?:</font></b><br>
<select type="drop" name="Selfserve" id="SSO">
<option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="n/a">n/a</option>
</select>  
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Problem:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Problem" id="problem" placeholder="Problem" 
cols="70"           rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Issue" id="issue2" placeholder="Issue" 
cols="70"                 rows="6"></textarea>    
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Action" id="action2" placeholder="Action" 
cols="70"             rows="10"></textarea>
<br>


</td>
<td valign="top">

<table border=0 height=100% ><tr><td valign="top" height=410>
<textarea type="textarea" name="form2output" 
onclick="this.focus();this.select()"         
id="output2" cols="70" 
rows="25" placeholder="Name:
Number:
Y N?:
Question?:&#x0a;
Notes:&#x0a;
Issue:&#x0a;
Action:"></textarea>
<br>

</td>

</tr>
  <tr><td valign=top>

  <div class="btn-group">
<button value="Combine" onclick="convert()">Combine</button> <br><br>
</div>


  </td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">




<table width=25% height=100% border=0><tr><td valign="bottom">

<div class="btn-group">
<button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
</div>

</form>

</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>

</div>
```

And the script

```
<script>
/*Reset command*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":reset").css("background-color", "");
 });
</script>

<script>
function wordwrap(str, width, brk, cut) {
brk = brk || '\n';
width = width || 60;
cut = cut || false;
if (!str)
return str;

var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : 
'|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join(brk);
}
function convert() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var question1 = document.getElementById("question1").value;
var question2 = document.getElementById("question2").value;
var notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;
var issue = document.getElementById("issue").value;
var action = document.getElementById("action").value;
//input = wordwrap(input, 70, true);

var output = "";

output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
output += "Number: " + phone + "\n";
output += "Question 1?: " + question1 + "\n";
output += "Question 2?: " + question2 + "\n\n";
output += "Notes: " + notes + "\n\n";
output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
output += "Action: " + action + " ";


document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}


function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}


</script>

<script>
function wordwrap(str, width, brk, cut) {
brk = brk || '\n';
width = width || 60;
cut = cut || false;

if (!str)
return str;

var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : 
'|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join(brk);
}

function convert() {
var Name2 = document.getElementById(name2").value;
var Currentnumber = document.getElementById("currentnumber").value;
var YESNO = document.getElementById("yesno").value;
var selfserve = document.getElementById("SSO").value;
var problem = document.getElementById("problem").value;
var issue2 = document.getElementById("issue2").value;
var action2 = document.getElementById("action2").value;
//input = wordwrap(input, 70, true);

var output = " ";

output += "Name2: " + name2 + "\n";
output += "Current number: " + currentnumber + "\n";
output += "Yes No?: " + yesno + "\n";
output += "Self Serve?: " + selfserve + "\n\n";
output += "Problem: " + problem + "\n\n";
output += "Issue: " + issue2 + "\n\n";
output += "Action: " + action2 + " ";


 document.getElementById("output2").value = output;
 }


function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
 }


 </script>
```

EDIT: I made the changes suggested by Ivo, but still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. You're also using the `<font>` element which doesn't exist, and tables for layout, which is a no-no.

Comment: It's been a long time since I played with any of this stuff. If tables are a no no now, what is a better way of managing page layout?

Comment: Seems like there are some HTML syntax errors, mismatched `<form>` tags. Also looks like you're defining three functions twice (one set for each form) with the same duplicate names.

Comment: I got lost experimenting. Here's a [simple working version](https://jsfiddle.net/qsu5nvxt/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id of the form2 textarea to `output2`:

```
<textarea type="textarea" name="form2output" 
onclick="this.focus();this.select()"               
id="output2" 
cols="70" rows="25" placeholder="Name:
Number:
Y N?:
Question?:&#x0a;
Notes:&#x0a;
Issue:&#x0a;
Action:"></textarea>
```

and change the line of js where you set the output for form2 to be:

```
 document.getElementById("output2").value = output;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's still not working, maybe I'm missing something? I added the ID to the output for "output2" and made the change to the JS, but still not outputting any results to the second textarea.

Comment: showdev made a much cleaner version with auto detection of the forms on the page at https://jsfiddle.net/qsu5nvxt/